# Parsing multiple XML files

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax

I have this XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Main>
  <class category="super">
    <property name="XML doc path">HERE IS PATH TO ANOTHER XML doc</title>
  </class>
  <class category="normal">
    <key>a451-47-aswx4</key>  // unique key of each class
    <property>some data</property>
    <edge>k4x8-74-aswx5</edge> // this is key of another class node and represents connection between them
  </class>
  .
  .
  .
</Main>
```

What I basically need to do while parsing the XML file in this format is to build a graph. That would not be a problem with a single XML file. But when I encounter a `tag name = class` with attribute `category = super` I have to start parsing another XML from given path. The order of parsing does not matter. I can parse new file immediately(recursively) or add the XML file path to queue and start parsing it after I have finished the current one.

I don't need to write to XML, just read from it. I read that SAX parser is quite fast and does not use that much of memory but I can't figure how to do this with SAX.

So the question is:

> Is it possible to somehow do it with java SAX parser ? If yes i would like to know the idea otherwise some alternatives.

Comment: do you have xsd(schema definition) of this xml.

Comment: Did you already try to use an xpath expression on the xml file asking for `"/class/property[name='XML doc path']/text()"`? If that query returns a set of nodes, then all its notes is one file that you need to parse and feed to the same logic again... Could this approach work? if yes, then I'd try to write a little longer text on this framed into an answer.

Comment: Can you change the xml format or is it given as-is? e.g. you could change it in a way that allows RDF parsers to work with it. This seems more appropriate.